# What were Iswaran's 9 dropped charges and why were they dropped?

Tags: corruption, singapore

In January 2024, Singaporean politician S. Iswaran resigned after being charged with corruption.

*The Straits Times* ([2024-01-18](https://www.straitstimes.com/singapore/courts-crime/former-transport-minister-s-iswaran-faces-27-charges-including-corruption-says-he-is-not-guilty)):

> [Iswaran's defence lawyer Davinder Singh] said cautioned statements were taken from Iswaran on 36 charges on Jan 15.
>
> He said the defence learnt on the morning of Jan 18 that there were now just 27 charges, and asked if the prosecution was proceeding with the remaining nine charges.
>
> The prosecution said it was not.

*Channel NewsAsia* ([2024-01-18](https://www.channelnewsasia.com/singapore/iswaran-charged-corruption-transport-minister-resigns-4054406)):

> "It would appear that in the matter of two days, a decision has been taken not to proceed with the nine charges," Mr Singh told the judge.
>
> "According to my learned friend, that is because they have reviewed all the evidence. But I would have thought, your honour, that the evidence would've been reviewed thoroughly before the 36 charges were levelled against my client on Monday. And so, for now, all I would say is that it is surprising but highly significant that after what I assumed was a thorough review and the levelling of the nine charges, in a matter of two days, there has been a complete change of position. I will say no more about that for now," said Mr Singh.

The 27 charges can be found [here](https://www.straitstimes.com/multimedia/graphics/2024/01/iswaran-27-charges/index.html) (*The Straits Times*, 2024-01-20).

But I can't find the other 9 dropped charges. What were they and why were they dropped?